# rails4 carrierwave + S3 adding new image version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a rails4 app, profile images are uploaded with carrierwave and served by S3.

I used to have one image version (`base_thumb`) for resizing. Now I'm trying to add `user_thumb`, but if I change the code from `profile.avatar.url(:base_thumb)` to `profile.avatar.url(:user_thumb)` then the image is not displayed to users who created profile earlier since that image version is not on S3.

How can I solve this issue?

```
version :base_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [85, 85]
end

version :user_thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [40, 40]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create new versions of each different size.  Carrierwave has a method for this.

You can read the doc here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#recreating-versions

but essentially you will run something like

```
Profile.find_each do |profile|
  profile.avatar.recreate_versions! if profile.avatar?
end
```